# how to set Header and Footer in react-pdf/renderer?

Tags: reactjs

[image]I am building reactJs app, I am using react-pdf/renderer to render the pdf. I want to show Header in the pdf.
Below is the my code.

```
MainComponent.jsx
              <Document>
                 <Page size="A4" style={styles.page}>
                 <MyFixedHeader style={{flex: 0.2}}/>
                 <Image style={styles.image} src={Logo} />
                 <Text style={styles.text}>
                     {pdfData}
                     </Text>
                 </Page>
             </Document>


MyFixedHeader.jsx
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export const MyFixedHeader = () => {

    return (<>
    hi
    </>)
}
```

By using this code, I am getting blank screen.

Thanks.

Comment: is it possible to share your code? Im also having a similar issue. Great help if you could share it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]

I added a screenshot of how to add a footer on each page end. here is the link https://react-pdf.org/repl you can test it here
@mehak

[image: New Image Playground]

[image]

are you applying these styles??

Comment: by using the above solution , I an not getting the text at end of the page, I am getting where the text ends

Comment: can you show me how you are doing I didn't get your point

Comment: did you pass the `fixed` prop ??

Comment: Yes i have added

Comment: <Document> <Page>   <Text  >
                            dfgfdgfdgfdgfdtr </Text>
                <Text  render={({ pageNumber, totalPages }) => (
                    `${pageNumber} / ${totalPages}`
                )} fixed />
                 </Page>
             </Document>

Comment: also i am rendering dynamic textand I want to make some heading bold how can i make it?

Comment: I added two new screenshots above you can check that

Answer (score 6):

[image]

you can check here official site https://react-pdf.org/advanced
and there are many different other ways to create Header and Footer for react-pdf

[image]

Added Horizontal Line

[image]

[image]

How to register Font?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: what issue are you facing??

Comment: can you share your code anywhere codesandbox etc please

Comment: @mehak I updated the above answer Please check

Comment: Can you please help me in adding horizontal line in header also?

Comment: How you want horizontal line

Comment: in header some image is there, to close the header i need to show horizontal line using the same lib

Comment: Updated above answer with horizontal line

Comment: how to get footer at the end of the page? currently I am getting it where my text ends. also I want some part of text at left, some at center and some at rigth?

Comment: let me check that

Comment: my text is overriding footer. How to get that before footer ends?

Comment: Can you attach screenshot please

Comment: What you want I didn't get that

Comment: i am adding footer at the end. I have given bottom as 30 and the content between header and footer is overlaping the footer text. header is working fine

Comment: i want padding between text and the footer

Comment: can you show me any reference screenshot??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234009/discussion-between-mehak-and-muhammad-bilal-bangash).

Comment: i have added screenshot in question

Comment: Hi, My text is overlapping footer view can you please help me out. I have added screenshot above

Comment: <PDFViewer > <Document> <Page size="A4" style={styles.page} ><View >  <Text> hi,</Text>  <View>{Details.clauses.map((x, i) => ( <View> <Text><Text > {x.heading} :  </Text>{" "}{x.description}</Text><Text> {x.nestedObj.length !== 0? x.nestedObj.map((val, i) => { return ( <Text> {val.nestedDesc}</Text>)}): ""}</Text></View>))}</View> </View><View style={styles.footer} fixed><hr style={styles.footerline} /><Text>www.google.com</Text></View> </Page></Document></PDFViewer>

Comment: const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    page: {
      flexDirection: "column",
      backgroundColor: "white",
      marginBottom : '10px'
    },
    section: {
      textAlign: "left",
      marginLeft: "50px",
      marginRight: "50px",
      fontSize: 10,
      fontFamily: "Open Sans",
      top: 5,
      bottom : 10,
      // marginBottom: "100px",
      paddingBottom : "100px",
    },

Comment: line: {
      border: "0.5px solid #cb2026",
      marginLeft: "50px",
      marginRight: "50px",
    },
    footerline: {
      border: "0.5px solid #cb2026",
    },
    topline: {
      border: "2px solid #cb2026",
    },
    bottomline: {
      border: "2px solid #cb2026",
      bottom: 0,
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
    },  bottomView: { bottom: 0, left: 0, right: 0, }, footer: {  position: "absolute",  fontSize: 8,  bottom: 15, left: 0, right: 0,textAlign: "left",  marginLeft: "50px",  marginRight: "50px", color: "#cb2026", }, });

Comment: unable to send in codesandbox..as i am passing data through props

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/delicate-glade-v7eie?file=/src/App.js

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-dawn-rezwz?file=/src/App.js check here also I added you in codesandbox repo if any question leave comment over there

Comment: Great answer! Well done!

Comment: Is there an easy way to just have the footer at the bottom of every page/wrapped-page ?